# passing input value from bash script to a c++ executable

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I have a c++ code which requires an input value. I would like to have a bash script to run my c++ executable file automatically. My bash script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ freshness.cpp -g -o prob
for((i=0;i<30;i++))
{
    ./prob<$2 ../../data/new_r.txt ../../data/new_p.txt ../../data  /t_$1.txt  >> result.txt
}
./cal result.txt
rm result.txt
```

My *main.cpp* is below:

```
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    map<int, struct Router> nodes;
    cout<<"creating routers..."<<endl;
    Create_router(argv[1],nodes);
    cout<<"creating topology..."<<endl;
    LoadRouting(argv[2],nodes);
    cout<<"simulating..."<<endl;
    Simulate(argv[3],nodes);
    return 0;
}
```

There is a `cin` in `Create_router(argv[1],nodes)`, like `cin>>r_size`;

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Comment: My bash script doesn't work. I don't know how to pass an input value from a bash script to a c++ executable file

Comment: @JaysonZhang, how are invoking the bash script?

Comment: Your script is using `$2` as the name of the file to get the program's input from. Is that what you want? If not, what do you really want?

Answer (score 2):

```
./prob < $2
```

means to redirect the input of the program to a file whose name is in the `$2` variable.

If `$2` is the actual input data, not a filename, then you should use a here-string:

```
./prob <<< "$2" ../../data/new_r.txt ../../data/new_p.txt ../../data  /t_$1.txt  >> result.txt
```

or a here-doc:

```
./prob <EOF ../../data/new_r.txt ../../data/new_p.txt ../../data  /t_$1.txt  >> result.txt
$2
EOF
```

or pipe the input to the program:

```
printf "%s\n" "$2" | ./prob ../../data/new_r.txt ../../data/new_p.txt ../../data  /t_$1.txt  >> result.txt
```

The here-string method is the simplest, but it's a `bash` extension. The other methods are portable to all POSIX shells.

Comment: Thank you so much.